# Disabling the "keep pressed" function of OS X sticky keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

I use the accessibility feature called sticky keys in OS X, what it does is that if you press a command modifier key (Ctrl, Cmd, Alt, Shift, Fn), it stays "pressed" until you press another key. This is very useful if you often use your keyboard with one hand, and actually quite convenient even when you use two hands.

The thing is that if you press a modifier key **twice** it stays "pressed" until you press it again. While it is sometimes handy, for me it would be **preferable if this aspect of the functionality could be disabled**, since I trigger it accidentally every now and then.

I realize that if this is at all possible it probably means fiddling with some system file somewhere, that's fine. I just want to see if someone out there might know where to look? :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I was really wondering about this post from 2011. There was some change on how the modifier keys get handled in sticky keys around 2016, in Sierra, maybe even El Capitan.

Comment: Check https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7687205 (already locked thread) and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250060393 (trying to inform people). My bug report (ID39265185) got closed. Apple doesn't care and they won't fix it ever.

Comment: Sadly it seems like there's no real solution for this now.  Sticky keys are great for ergonomics and reducing fatigue, but the "tap twice to lock" functionality is invoked on accident 90% of the time.  (Though for some people, it's certainly a critical feature, just wish it had a toggle)

Answer (score 5):

You can't turn off the "key lock" functionality (last checked on OS X 10.8.2). You can however install [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html), which allows you to make modifier keys sticky without this "key lock".

**2023 update**: KeyRemap4MacBook functionality has been rolled into [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) by the same developer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll see if it's usable for me though.

It's such a pity that there's no option for this, because sticky keys is such a convenient feature!

Comment: Ended up not using KeyRemap4MacBook, didn't feel comfortable with it.

Comment: just fyi, i [added this setting](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/pull/118) to KeyRemap4MacBook yesterday. it's available in version 8.0.33; it's called 'Enable Sticky Modifier Keys (without lock feature)'.

@Devon, i've been using it with lots of combined shortcuts like you mention, and it's pretty reliable.

Comment: @ryan, The problem with KeyRemap still exists, but I've created a proper bug report for it now.

Comment: The KeyRemap4MacBook bug has [fixed](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/issues/119) as of version 8.0.34.

Comment: It's 2023 but this question still comes up pretty high on Google. I also am frustrated by the un-disable-able "press twice to lock" behavior of the built in macOS Sticky Keys. KeyRemap4MacBook seems to have become or has been rolled into Karabiner-Elements from the same developer and it supports non-locking sticky keys out of the box:  https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can get this behavior by using a third-party program called "Karabiner-Elements"

Leave **Enable Sticky Keys** unchecked in **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Keyboard** > **Hardware**.

Instead, open "Karabiner-Elements" and click **Simple modifications**. Then select **Add item** > **From key** > **left_shift** and under **To key** > **sticky left_shift**. Repeat for right_shift and optionally Option, Command, Control.

You might also want to investigate the function "sticky left_shift (pressing and holding down is disabled)."

I've noticed problems with Apple's sticky keys feature ever since upgrading to Mac OS 12.2. And a discussion about it on support.apple.com indicates Apple is unwilling to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior even when "sticky keys" is turned off in system settings, by unchecking the "enable sticky keys" checkbox.  I was seeing shift stuck "on" only for OS actions (not for normal typing) after coming back from a lock screen.

To resolve this, I turned sticky keys on (Mac Settings) and then toggled them off again using the shortcuts above.

Comment: I had the same problem! It was impossible to google, produced some strange behavior before I figured out it was as if I were holding Shift down. Yes, if your password includes capital letters, then Shift might get forced "on" after the lock screen. Just discovered that toggling sticky keys off and on solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to press it 3 times to release it.

- First Press - Locks the modifier key, and unlocks it after the next key press
- Second Press - Locks the modifier key for multiple other key presses.
- Third Press - Unlocks the modifier.

Exmaple:

Pressing Shift twice while sticky keys is on would be the same result as turning on CAPS lock.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm asking for a way to disable the "locked" state altogether. I think it's pretty clear from the wording of my question. :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I misunderstood. I don't know of a way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

go in to system pref, accessibility, keybord (left column) sticky keys, options, then "press shift five times to toggle sticky keys"

Comment: This disables the functionality altogether, the asker only wants to disable the "lock" part you get by pressing a modifier twice (but still use the single press functionality).

Comment: my apologies, i misunderstood the question then